# how to update existing data and add new data in array of objects in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I am having mongoose schema to store user response. i have to ask question from users and save their responses in database as soon as user answer.

```
 userResponse: [{
                type: Object
            }]
```

Whenever i am inserting data in userResponse it stored successfully...
I am using below code to store userResponse in db:

```
data = req.body
     await customerManager.updateCustomer(
                {
                    email: "kehom35319@nzaif.com",
                },
                {
                    $push: {
                        userResponse: data
                    }
                }
            );
```

For example I am storing below object:

when user answer question number 1, i will store response in db

```
 {
       "questionId": 1,
    "question" : "what is your full name",
       "questionRes":{"FirstName":"Manoj", "LastName": "Kumawat"}
    }
```

when user answer question number 2, i will store response in db

```
{
       "questionId": 2,
    "question" : "what is your age",
       "questionRes":22
    }
```

When i console the stored userResponses in db, I get below result:

```
"userResponse": [
            {
                "questionId": 1,
                "question": "what is your full name",
                "questionRes": {
                    "FirstName": "Manoj",
                    "LastName": "Kumawat"
                }
            },
            {
                "questionId": 2,
                "question": "what is your age",
                "questionRes": 22
            }
        ]
```

Now suppose user goes back to question 1 and made changes in answer and than api will hit to save changes in db. Instead of saving new changes in question number 1, it adds the new object in userResponse.
below is the result, when user go back and change answer of question 1

```
 "userResponse": [
            {
                "questionId": 1,
                "question": "what is your full name",
                "questionRes": {
                    "FirstName": "Manoj",
                    "LastName": "Kumawat"
                }
            },
            {
                "questionId": 2,
                "question": "what is your age",
                "questionRes": 22
            },
            {
                "questionId": 1,
                "question": "what is your full name",
                "questionRes": {
                    "FirstName": "Abhishek",
                    "LastName": "Sharma"
                }
            }
        ]
```

I want that whenever user make changes in questions that they already answered than only i need to reflect changes in corresponding to the question number in db. I don't wan't to save duplicate questions.

Comment: I don't have much experience in mongoose. But here is the logic I suggest:
1. You need to know which question a user is answering.
2. Then you GET that question from your db by ID and UPDATE that question only.

Comment: I need that code...

Comment: Are you using Express for server?

Comment: yes, i am using express in nodejs

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post('/userResponse', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const updatedSchema = await userResponse.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.body.id, 
      {$set: {questionRes: ...req.body.response}}
    );
    res.status(300).json({
      status: success,
      message: 'Successfully updated the table'
    })
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({
      status: fail,
      message: error
    })
  }
  
});
```

I am guessing you are parsing requests as JSON and send the response to the question as an object (called response). Also, you need to POST data to '/userResponse' route.